# Is potty-training in 3 days possible?

Tags: toddler, potty-training

I want to potty train my 2-year-old, and I read about [The 3 Day Potty Training Method](http://www.3daypottytraining.com/) which claims is possible to do it in 3 days! Has anyone tried this method?

Comment: i'd be a bit skeptical if the only way to find out if this works is by paying $24usd...

Comment: i already have the book, ;) some one gave me a copy

Comment: hmmm.  i don't believe you can rush a good thing ... http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-can-i-potty-train-a-12-month-old .. let me know how you get on ...

Comment: Please, let us know if it worked for you!..

Comment: Some people say it works.  Some people say it trains you more than the child.  Changing diapers is not the difficult part of parenthood so why worry about it?  It'll happen.  How many adults do you know who aren't potty trained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the book, but I can tell you my experience with my first child. He started showing interest in bathroom and waking up with a dry diaper. My wife was on vacation and I was going to have a long weekend so we decided to give it a try.

We sat down with him and explained the whole thing, and how he was now a big boy and he was ready to use the potty. At first it was very scary for him. Sitting was fun, we read him a story or showed him a video from Elmo, and he was very happy, but when he felt he was about to pee, he started yelling a lot, as if it was a bad thing. We faced the same situation on a previous attempt and we quit trying then. But know we kept on trying, we told him everything was going to be alright and it was OK to pee in the potty. He finally did it and started to be less scared every time. Every time he pee in the potty we gave him a price such as a gummy bear or a little chocolate. Next day he was going every time with just one accident and he has been fine ever since.

He was on his underwear the whole time (no training diapers, except when we went to the store or grandma's). And at night we would sleep with his training diapers. After a month or so without wetting the training diapers, we decided that he could sleep without them.

I think the most important thing is to notice when the kid is ready and make him as comfortable as possible. If there are accidents, don't make a big deal out of it, just have him help you out to clean. If he succeeds, make sure to make a big deal and regard him with hugs and maybe a little treat as well.

So to sum up, it is possible, my kid had it almost completely at day 2, but I'm sure it depends completely on each kid. I've heard parents saying that theirs did it on day one, some take more than a week.

Comment: How old was your son then?

Comment: He was two years old

Comment: I have not read any literature on the subject, but in all my conversations with fellow parents there is one universal truth: every kid is different. Bottom line though: if your child is ready, then yes, it is possible. But only if they are actually, sincerely ready.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't rush it, unnecessarily.  You can take it slow and let your child learn at their own pace. Putting a timeline to it only stresses you and them out needlessly.

Every kid is different. Be consistent with him/her. Be patient and loving with them and they will learn in 3 days or 3 months.

*Our own kids were different -- Our oldest took 7 days. (He had just turned 3). Our youngest did it in 2 days (maybe one accident?) and he was 2 and 1/2 at the time. One boy in the neighborhood took 2 months. Bottom line, doesn't matter how long it takes. As all three of them are now toilet-masters :)*

Answer (score 3):

I read the book, however, my kido took almost a fortnight to get used to it.
 "HOW TO" books do not consider the individual personality types.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the physical and emotional development of the child it may be possible.  Keep in mind that some kids can't hold it while sleeping until they are much older regardless of their desire to do so.  That being said, when we pulled the trigger thats how long it took with one of my kids (if you don't count the very occasional accident for a time).  The other one took a little longer.  I think that you should consider carefully if they are ready and when you do pull the trigger, to not go half way.  You have to be committed to watch them like a hawk and help them succeed, prevent and deal with night-time accidents, etc.  An incremental approach is bound to bring conflict, foot dragging, and begging by both the parent and child.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it is possible to do it in 3 days, but you have to wait until the child is actually ready. They should be showing interest, and waking up dry, etc. Like the first author says. If the parent is the one initiating the process, it is going to take however much time it takes until the child is ready. Better to just wait until they've mastered the physical skills necessary instead of trying to force something you can't.