# Is using a potty described in this video for 1 month++ old baby safe?

Tags: potty-training, stools

Is using a potty described in this video for 1 month++ old baby safe?

I'm referring to supporting the child on the potty as he poops. My wife is strongly against it as there is no support for the baby's back. but I find her way of pooping too messy.

She rest the baby on the changing table and induce him to poop by saying "umm umm umm".

The baby poop all over the place and need to periodically clean his poop for new poop to come out.

I'm considering support the baby on the potty and induce him to poop by saying "umm umm ummm".

[Video - Baby Potty Training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw3oLxgdAVY)

Comment: What strikes you as "unsafe"?

Comment: Do you mean the overall method of elimination communication, or specific positioning, or what? Please clarify so this is answerable.

Comment: Referring the the position and it will be good to know which area is unsafe too.

Comment: See related question http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/91/48

Answer (score 1):

I think any potty would be safe, as long as you supervise and support your child when on the potty.